API to enable clients to access LiDAR data
I am new to GIS, and need some ideas here.
I am working on developing a web application. I have LiDAR data stored in large number of files. I want to provide API to clients which would enable them to access this data for some inputs, say a bounding box. So API would enable clients to access all LiDAR data in the input bounding box.
But as LiDAR data is huge, so I want to explore the efficient ways of enabling this workflow.
My initial inclination is that I may need to convert LiDAR data to some industry format format that is more suitable to this usecase, like maybe OGS's 3D tiles, and store them at some location, like cesium's asset store or some cloud.
When request comes to API, application would need to determine which 3D tiles would meet bounding box condition, and then I can send back URLs of those tiles to clients.
I would like to hear from GIS experts on this topic.

Idea solicitation is not a good fit with our Focused question/Best answer model. The Help Center advises against cases where "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers". In theory, this could be asked in [chat], but the participation volume is much lower in Chat.

GeoServer and a WCS endpoint

My approach would be

Create overview shapes of your data files. For each data file store its bounding box and the filename or the full link to the file on your own server or in some cloud, if you want your data in some cloud. This can be done using a combination of the laspy python library and geopandas/fiona/shapely/..., for example. ChatGPT creates decent code for that if you ask write a script in python that reads a directory of las files using the laspy library and creates a overview shapefile that contains each las bounding box and the original filename as an attribute.
Import these overview shape files to a geoserver instance. Geoserver is a geoserver (duh!) that has (amongst others) OGC WFS APIs. See https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html for different output formats. Your client then can issue wfs requests and parse the response.


So if input boundingbox has partial overlap with a shapefile, then I can find that intersection and send response accordingly?
